# Declaring a DataTable and adding columns outside the method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to declare a **DataTable** outside the **Page_Load** method (or any other method)
 but unable to do so.

I want some thing like this.

```
Protected void Page_load(object sender ,EventArgs e) 
{
// Outside this or any other method
}
DataTable dt = new DataTable("testingDt");

dt.Columns.Add("Site A");
dt.Columns.Add("Site B");
dt.Columns.Add("Site C");
```

I can declare a DataTable and add columns inside methods and do whatever i want with them but was thinking why i am unable to some thing like this.

Answer (score 4):

As Habib has [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929498/declaring-a-datatable-and-adding-columns-outside-the-method/13929517#13929517):

> You can declare and instantiate the datatable outside of your method, but you can't add columns to it outside of the method.

I would not declare it outside of a method in ASP.NET since all objects are disposed of at the end of the current [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) anyway. That would encourage nasty bugs if you forget this fact.

Instead I would use a meaningful named method to initialize and fill your `DataTable`.

For example:

```
public static DataTable GetAllLinks()
{
    DataTable dtSelectedLinks = new DataTable();
    // fill it here from database or whatever ...
    return dtSelectedLinks;
}
```

Now you can use it wherever, for example:

```
Protected void Page_load(object sender ,EventArgs e) 
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        gridViewLinks.DataSource = GetAllLinks();
        gridViewLinks.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and instantiate the datatable outside of your method, but you can't add columns or perform any opreation on it outside of the method.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("testingDt"); // DataTable declared outside
Protected void Page_load(object sender ,EventArgs e) 
{
dtSelectedLinks.Columns.Add("Site A"); //Datatable used inside the method. 
dtSelectedLinks.Columns.Add("Site B");
dtSelectedLinks.Columns.Add("Site C");
}
```

Comment: Sorry i put the Question in hurry. I can do something like this. But i want to add columns outside the methods

Comment: @user1884709, you can't do that. You can only add the columns inside a method

Comment: For this situation what would be the best way you would do. I wanted to have a dataTable and then add Rows to it in some methods and then bind it. How would Habib do?

Comment: @user1884709, you can have separate method where you are creating your datatable structure. Define a datatable at page level, then add columns in it , later you can add rows to it. You may see [@Tim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13929568/961113), which is exactly how you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add columns/rows etc. to it

```
DataTable dt;
Protected void Page_load(object sender ,EventArgs e) 
{
     if(!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
        myGridView.DataSource=GetData();
        myGridView.DataBind();
     }
}

Private DataTable GetData()
{
     dt = new DataTable("testingDt");
     dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("S.No",typeof(int)));  
     dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name",typeof(string)));
     // Add rows
     return dt;
}
```